# call relation in Pivot model

Tags: php, eloquent, relationship

I try load relations like:

```php
 return $task->load('users', 'creator', 'attachments', 'messages.creator');
```

Relation 'users' many to many with some fields

```
user
 id
 name
 ...
task
 id
 name
 ...
task_user
 user_id
 task_id
 task_status_id
```

my pivot model

```php
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Pivot;

class TaskUser extends Pivot
{
    public $incrementing = true;

    public function status()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(TaskStatus::class);
    }
}
```

How to correctly load 'status' relation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If Laravel provided a way to pass Closures in pivots it wouldn't be hard at all however there are 2 solutions at the moment to load pivot relationships

## 1. Lazy eager load everything.

```php
# App\Task.php

public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(App\User::class)->using(App\TaskUser::class)->withPivot('task_status_id');
}
```

```php
$task->load('users', ...);
$task->users->each(function ($user) {
    $user->pivot->load('status');
});
```

The problem: This makes a query for each User related to Task. Unless you paginate your results, it's the classic N+1 problem.

## 2. Use hasMany and belongsTo instead.

- Define $user->tasks_user relationship (User hasMany TaskUser)
- Define $task->tasks_user relationship (Task hasMany TaskUser)
- Define the inverse (TaskUser belongsTo User, TaskUser belongsTo Task)
- Define the last task_user relationship (TaskUser hasOne TaskStatus) (looks like a belongsTo to me though)
- Load relationships `$task->load('task_user.user', 'task_user.status')`

There's no real problem with this implementation besides not using `belongsToMany`.